# How do you make an RPGLE program write SQL warnings and errors to the job log?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle, embedded-sql

It seems like I remember writing an RPG program that used embedded SQL that wrote a message to the interactive user job log whenever a SQL warning or error occurred.  I did not have to explicitly write it; it logged it by default.

The program i am writing now is not doing this logging although I know I can cause warnings like `01003` and errors like `02000` and read them with the `SQLState` variable.

I don't think I imagined this behavior.  Is there a H spec keyword that I forgot to set, the way I am calling the program (using `CALL` interactive), the way I wrote the SELECT INTO statement (static as opposed to dynamic)?  I am at a loss for other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SqlStates `00000`, `01###`, and `02###` do not produce logs though other states do. I would explicitly write anything to the log that you want to see there. You can easily write a sub-procedure that you can call after each sql statement to do the logging.

Comment: "Ding!"  Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a project which contains a service program for messages. It was a part of the RPGUnit project. I have put it into a separate project so it can be easily reused. https://bitbucket.org/m1hael/message

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the program is being run in a job with logging off..

DSPJOB  --> 2. Display job definition attributes

**Provides the most logging...**

```
Message logging:                                               
  Level . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   4        
  Severity  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   0        
  Text  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *SECLVL  
Log CL program commands . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *YES  
Job log output  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *JOBEND
```

**provides basically no logging...**

```
Message logging:                                               
  Level . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   0        
  Severity  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   99        
  Text  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *NOLIST
Log CL program commands . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *NO  
Job log output  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *JOBEND
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to check this, but right now it is at `Level = 4`, `Severity = 0`, `Text = *SECLVL`, `Log CL commands = *YES`, and `Job log output = *JOBEND`, exactly what you call the most logging configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Run your job in debug mode (STRDBG UPDPROD(*YES)) to get additional diagnostics from all database operations.

Comment: This will produce more logs, but will also affect performance.